# null infinite product in the p-adic setting

Tags: p-adic-analysis, p-adic-numbers, p-adic

Let $p$ be a prime, $\mathbb C_p$ be the completion of a algebraic closure of $\mathbb Q_p$ and $(u_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be a sequence of $\mathbb C_p$ converging towards $0$. Suppose that for all $n\in\mathbb N$, one has $1+u_n\ne0$. Can $\prod_{n\in\mathbb N}(1+u_n)$ be zero?

I know that is trivially true in $\mathbb C$, but I do not have any exemple (or  counterexemple) in $\mathbb C_p$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Am I missing something? the product _can_ be zero in $\mathbb C$: just take $u_n=-1/n$..

Comment: My mistake. I had a problem with negation :) I rewrite the post.

Comment: You're asking whether the sum of the $\log(1+u_n)$ (which is well defined for $n$ large enough) can diverge. But $\log(1+u_n)\to 0$ so the sum of them converges $p$-adically. Did I miss something?

Comment: You say it's trivially true in C but in my mind the argument for C_p is even easier: can't you just mimic the argument you know in C? The product converges and you can even see what the norm of the product is, it's just the product of the norms of 1+u_n over the u_n for which |u_n|>=1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $n_0$ is such that $|u_n|<1$ for $n \geq n_0$, then $|1+u_n| = 1$ for $n \geq n_0$, so the norm of the infinite product is the norm of the product of the first $n_0$ terms and hence nonzero.